# How to remove a record from bash tab completion options

Tags: bash, auto-completion

Every time I type "ssh use" in my bash terminal and press tab the command gets completed to "ssh username.dreamhosters.com" but that was not what I was looking for. How can I remove that entry from the list of possible completions?

Comment: bash-completion takes its suggestions from several sources, one of them is (for `ssh`) the contents of `~/.ssh/config` - where you can store parameters for your ssh-connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing it from `~/.ssh/known_hosts` may work - but this will remove the trusted connection thing if it works at all.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Although tab completion now doesn't find anything with that beginning. I thought it should now find the ssh command I use all the time.

Comment: I just guessed that it would search the known_hosts file for what to complete - glad it worked =)